# Import a big amount of data and return it without storing

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, web-frontend

I'm using Laravel for the backend.

I've an issue when i would like to import a big amount of data from a .xlsx file :

When an user want to import his data from a file, the process is made in 6 steps :

1. The user send his file to the server
2. The server store this file and return the full-path with a preview of unformatted data
3. The user make a configuration of the structure of the importation and send it to the server (linking the fullpath)
4. The server process and filters the data and send it back
5. The user have a preview of imported data with is config and then have to confirm the importation by sending back received data from step 4
6. Server stores the data in database.

My problem here, is when there is a big amount of data to import (ex : 30 000 lines) my server is trying to send 30 000 data at step **(4)**, that cause a CORS policy problem, I would like to make a pagination, but as at this step datas are not stored.

My idea was to segment data sent at step 4 by providing an offset to the server to process data from this offset to a constant given...

I would like to know if there is no other solution to avoid this problem...

And someone can confirm me that CORS policy problem comes from that big amount of data send by the nginx server ?

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://my-api.com/product' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

When the uploaded file is small (~10 000 lines) the problem didn't append, for >~ 30 000 lines I got this error.

Comment: What exactly is the "CORS policy problem" you mention? If you are getting an error message please [edit] your question and include the exact text of the error message.

Comment: the problem is not about size of the data, it's just a CORS problem. You must configure your backend `my-api.com/product` to add the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with the correct value to allow localhost from calling it. Try to find a CORS module for laravel

Comment: So can you explain me why with a small file, the import works and all my others routes ?

Comment: Your (3) step sounds like it could be a security leak if your server processes paths received from the client without further validation and authorization. But that just aside. Your problem itself has nothing to do with size (maybe that's an additional issue created by the max upload or post size of your PHP instance or nginx or apache). It has probably to do with you importing and processing all the data at once instead of chunking, but that's just a guess.

Comment: So processing my data by segment by sending an offset could be the solution right?

Comment: Is the upload and response done with one XHR? Does the server respond with a proper `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header when the dataset is small? What is the response status when the dataset is small? What is the response status when the dataset is large?

Comment: You need to also check the HTTP status code of the response in the case where you get the error (in the case where you say the file is larger than 30,000 lines). You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check the status code. You’ll find that in that case, the server is responding with 4xx or 5xx error — e.g., 413 Payload Too Large, or something. The only reason you also see that CORS message is servers by default typically never add CORS headers to 4xx and 5xx responses.

Comment: I've a 200 code for small amount of data, and 500 for big amount... So do you think is the CORS message comes from a timeout from the server ?